# Unable to parse info from webpage

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to parse info from this link on my node.js project
https://stockx.com/api/products/nike-daybreak-undercover-black?includes=market

Im able to get info when I access the link through postman and going on the url on a web browser. However when I try accessing the request through my node.js project, it is saying access is denied. Any idea why?
Thanks.
Here is my code:

```
const express = require('express');
const request = require('request');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const axios = require('axios')
const app     = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res){
   let shoe =req.query.shoe;
    let url = 'https://stockx.com/api/products/nike-daybreak-undercover-black?includes=market'
    request(url, function(error, response, html) {

        if (!error) {
          var $ = cheerio.load(html);
          console.log(html)

          res.send();
        }

    });

});
app.listen('8080');
console.log('API is running on http://localhost:8080');
module.exports = app;
```

Comment: [Why not just use the SDK](https://github.com/stockx/PublicAPI/tree/master/sdk/nodejs) with an API key??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add "User-Agent" in the header. The website from which you are trying to get the data is denying all requests without User-Agent to avoid **scrapers**.

```
const options = {
    url: 'https://stockx.com/api/products/nike-daybreak-undercover-black?includes=market',
    headers: {
        'User-Agent': 'request'
    }
};
request(options, function(error, response, html) {
    console.log('err: ', error);

    if (!error) {
        var $ = cheerio.load(html);
        console.log(html)

        res.send(html);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the following code and it works

```js
// ...
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  //  let shoe =req.query.shoe;
    let url = 'https://stockx.com/api/products/nike-daybreak-undercover-black?includes=market'

    axios({
      method : 'get',
      url,
      headers : { withCredentials: true, 'User-Agent' : 'Postman' }
    })
    .then(data => {
      console.log('data', data.data);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log('err', err);
    })
    res.send().status(200);
});
```